# How to correctly implement REST API when using custom filter

Tags: api, rest, architecture, backend

Let's say I have 2 entities in my app: **Platform** and **Publication**. **Publications** are placed at **Platforms** for a certain period of time.

```
Platform { id: number; name: string }
Publication { id: number; publish_at: timestamp; unpublish_at: timestamp }
```

So, I need an endpoint where I can send array of time intervals (Array<{start: timestamp; end: timestamp}>) and get array of platforms, where are no publications intersected with sent time intervals, in other worlds - platforms available for publishing in these time intervals.

At start I made simple POST endpoint named like **/api/available-platforms**, with custom input parameters `(Array<{start: timestamp; end: timestamp}>)`.

Now I'm trying to implement REST API architecture style in my app.
What is the right way of making the endpoint above in REST way?

Answer (score 1):

The most RESTful approach will be doing a GET **/platforms** with the interval filter as query parameter (in this case JSON encoded). In the case your URL get too long (you will run into a URL length limitation problem) I suggest using a POST with body. I know doing a POST does not fit too much the REST paradigm but it is better than doing a GET with body (which is by far less standard).